Changing color after a sublist changes vertical spacing
Edit: related to \color inserts unwanted vertical space in itemize

I'm working with lists using itemize and I need to put the lists side by side. No need for help so far.
I also want to use color to highlight some part of the list. When I use \color between \items things works fine, but I noticed when a color change occurs after a sub list, the vertical spacing is modified.
This is a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \color{blue}  % this color change is ok
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One
        \item Two
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 6
    \item Item 7
    \item Item 8
\end{itemize}
\hrulefill
\vfill

\pagebreak

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One
        \item Two
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 3
    \item {Item 4
        \begin{itemize}
            \item One
            \item Two
            \item Three
        \end{itemize}}
    \color{red}  % this color change adds extra space before "Item 6"
    \item Item 6
    \item Item 7
    \item Item 8
\end{itemize}
\hrulefill
\vfill

\end{document}

Both lists have the same contents. Changing the color to blue has no noticeable effect in the space between items and, for example, "Item 3" and "Item 4" are perfectly aligned in both lists.
When adding \color{red} after \end{itemize} the red "Item 6" and every other item after it is noticeably lower than their blue counterparts. Somehow \color is messing with the space between items.

Is there a way to avoid this extra spacing without changing the color of each item individually?

Related: \color inserts unwanted vertical space in itemize

Precisely. Thanks for the edition. And that discussion is 8 yr old...

The problem is that \color{red} will trigger insertion of \parsep glue.
Remove it.
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \color{blue}  % this color change is ok
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One
        \item Two
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 6
    \item Item 7
    \item Item 8
\end{itemize}
\hrulefill
\vfill

\pagebreak

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One
        \item Two
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
        \begin{itemize}
            \item One
            \item Two
            \item Three
        \end{itemize}
    \color{red}\vspace{-\parsep}  % this color change adds extra space before "Item 6"
    \item Item 6
    \item Item 7
    \item Item 8
\end{itemize}
\hrulefill
\vfill

\end{document}



Interesting! Why in the example \color{blue} doesn't add a \parsep while \color{red} does? The \end{itemize} perhaps?

@Jander Yes that’s the difference
